# Getting items from [Any?] in a ForEach loop to display text

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below is some code I have been trying

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnyOptional: View {
    private var optionalArray: [Any?] = [1, 2, 3]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(optionalArray) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Optional: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self as! String }
}

struct AnyOptional_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnyOptional()
    }
}
```

I had a similar problem with [String] which I solved by using this extension

```
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

but now I get an error saying Any? must inherit from NSObject.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use your already created `id` extension:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(optionalArray) { i in
            Text(i.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that not all objects can be casted down to String (`self as! String` will fail if the object can't be cast to String).

---

A better way is to use `String(describing:)`.

For this you can create another extension (updated to remove the word *Optional* if there's some value):

```
extension Optional {
    public var asString: String {
        if let value = self {
            return .init(describing: value)
        }
        return .init(describing: self)
    }
}
```

and use it in the `ForEach` loop:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(optionalArray, id: \.asString) { i in
            Text(i.asString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I have found your solution better as it doesn't force unwrap and hence doesn't fail when the data returns nil. just now its Optional(" ") so just got to work on dealing this these

Comment: @HenryHudson I updated the extension to remove *Optional* form `asString`.